# What are Legitimate uses of const_cast

Tags: c++, constants

Since with help of `const_cast` anyone can modify my declared constant object - what use is the `const` qualifier?

I mean how can someone ensure that what he declared `const` is not going to be modified anyway?

Comment: It's the same as with `reinterpret_cast`, `union`, `memcpy` and many others: There's always a way to circumvent safety mechanisms in C++, mostly invoking undefined behaviour. That you can break them doesn't mean that these mechanisms don't provide benefit.

Comment: "what he has declared as a const is not going to modified anyways??" By convention, a `const`-qualified object won't change its *observable behaviour*. It doesn't mean that it's bits won't be modified.

Comment: Lazy evaluation (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881119/dealing-with-lazy-computation-in-c-classes), but probably using mutable is better than e.g. const_cast<...>(this).

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673508/correct-usages-of-const-cast

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are right, uses of `const_cast` often indicates a design flaw, or an API that is out of your control.

However, there is an exception, it's useful in the context of overloaded functions. I'm quoting an example from the book *C++ Primer*:

```
// return a reference to the shorter of two strings
const string &shorterString(const string &s1, const string &s2)
{
    return s1.size() <= s2.size() ? s1 : s2;
}
```

This function takes and returns references to `const string`. We can call the function on a pair of non-const `string` arguments, but we’ll get a reference to a `const string` as the result. We might want to have a version of `shorterString` that, when given non-const arguments, would yield a plain reference. We can write this version of our function using a `const_cast`:

```
string &shorterString(string &s1, string &s2)
{
    auto &r = shorterString(const_cast<const string&>(s1),
                            const_cast<const string&>(s2));
    return const_cast<string&>(r);
}
```

This version calls the const version of `shorterString` by casting its arguments to references to `const`. That function returns a reference to a `const string`, which we
know is bound to one of our original, non-const arguments. Therefore, we know it is safe to cast that string back to a plain `string&` in the return.

Comment: I would note that this example is a poorly illustrated in that **adding** a `const` qualifier does not require a cast. So only one is truly needed (the last).

Comment: @MatthieuM. Without the casts adding const, you'd get infinite recursion.

Comment: @Angew: I did not mean that adding the `const` was useless, I meant that using `const_cast` to add it was overkill. For example, you could use a [static_cast](http://ideone.com/tvhMkf) to the same effect.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I'd argue that `const_cast` is the proper tool here. With `static_cast`, you could accidentally change the type. But that's mostly a matter of coding style.

Comment: Better yet use boost implicit cast for adding the const.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: did not even know this one :)

Comment: @Angew: It is arguable indeed, it is just that any use of `const_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` is **potentially dangerous**, and thus using it for what could be an implicit conversion... Note that if we quit the one-liner world: `auto const& ss1 = s1; ...` will achieve the same effect with no spurious `const_cast`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree that creating an `auto const &` is indeed the best option.

Answer (score 8):

Nobody can modify your constant object, with `const_cast` or without it. `const_cast` does not allow one to modify constant objects.

When it comes to removing constness, the purpose of `const_cast` is to allow you remove constness from an *access path* (pointer or reference) that leads to a *non*-constant object.

For example

```
int i = 5;
const int *p = &i;

*const_cast<int *>(p) = 10;
assert(i == 10);
```

In the above code `const_cast` is used to gain modifying access to object `i` through pointer `p`. Object `i` is not constant itself, so there's nothing wrong with that modification.

That's the purpose of `const_cast`. It can also be used for the opposite purpose: *adding* constness to pointer or reference type. But "modifying constant objects" is not something you can do with `const_cast`. Constant objects are not modifiable.

Comment: Is that right? The code `const int x = 42; int *px = const_cast<int *>(&x); *px = 3;` appears to modify the memory.

Answer (score 7):

`const_cast` is only safe if you are adding `const` to an originally non-const variable. Trying to remove the `const` status from an originally-const object, and then perform the write operation on it will result in undefined behavior.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357600/is-const-cast-safe) is related.

Also, the msdn page says (emphasis mine):

> A pointer to any object type or a pointer to a data member can be explicitly converted to a type that is identical except for the const, volatile, and __unaligned qualifiers. For pointers and references, the result will refer to the original object. For pointers to data members, the result will refer to the same member as the original (uncast) pointer to data member. **Depending on the type of the referenced object, a write operation through the resulting pointer, reference, or pointer to data member might produce undefined behavior.
>   You cannot use the const_cast operator to directly override a constant variable's constant status.**

Comment: I thought that non-const to const was an upcast and didn't need explicit cast?

Comment: @JanDvorak For some pointer conversions, it's required, such as from `int**` to `int const**`.

Comment: Another point: You can safely remove the `const` from any object that hasn't been declared `const`. `int i; int const* p = &i; int* pp = const_cast<int*>(p); *pp = 42;` is safe.

Comment: @DyP, that's why it says "depending on the type of the referenced object" ;)

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I was referring to your own text before that quote "If you will try to remove the const with it, you will get UB." This isn't complete/precise in two ways: 1) UB will only occur if you do a write-operation on that object 2) UB will only occur if the object itself is const (has been defined as const)

Comment: @DyP, I've tried to rephrase it to make it more clear, thanks.

Comment: @DyP I can't see why it should be required

Comment: @JanDvorak [See the C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/constptrptr-conversion.html)

Answer (score 3):

One possible use for `const_cast` to cast away constness, is to call C functions that don't use `const` arguments but still doesn't modify their arguments, or only modifies their local copies.

Casting away the `const` part and then modify the data will most certainly lead to undefined behavior otherwise.